# Ways to prove that $n$-component Brunnian link is nontrivial

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, fundamental-group

The attached image shows a way to construct an $n$-component Brunnian link for any $n\geq 3$. That is, this link is not trivial, but deleting any of its components makes the new link trivial. The latter property is obvious from the picture, however I would like to have a strict proof of nontriviality. What bothers me is that *nowhere* in the literature there is an example of proving nontriviality of any Brunnian $n$-link.

Let us denote this link by $L=K_1\cup K_2 \cup \dotsb \cup K_{n-1}\cup K_n$. Also, it might be useful to examine $L'=L\setminus K_n=K_1\cup K_2 \cup \dotsb \cup K_{n-1}$.
I tried to look at the link group $\pi_1(L').$ Since $L'$ is equivalent to $n-1$ disjoint circles, I conclude that $\pi_1(L')=F_{n-1}$. Then I ask what $[K_n]\in \pi_1(L')$ would be in the case if $L$ were trivial. In that case I would be able to move $K_n$ a little bit and get a homotopic loop that is a clean circle, thus $[K_n]\in \pi_1(L')$ is the identity.
Now, for contradiction I would like to calculate explicit form of $[K_n]\in \pi_1(L')$ (or to somehow just prove that it is not the identity). I tried doing it with Wirtinger presentation, but it was messy and, even if I did find explicit form for $[K_n]\in \pi_1(L')$ in terms of group’s generators correctly, determining whether $[K_n]$ is equal to the identity in this finitely generated group is a well-known undecidable problem.

Is there a way to improve my approach in order to prove nontriviality? If not, do you see another way to prove that? Actually, just an example of proof of nontriviality for any $n$-component Brunnian link would be enough for me, chances are the idea would work for many Brunnian links if not for all.

[image]

Comment: You can prove this using Milnor’s invariants, which are generalizations of linking numbers.  See his paper “Link groups”.  By the way, the classical decision problems for fundamental groups of 3-manifolds like link exteriors are all decidable.  See here for a summary of the literature on them: https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.0202

Comment: Your statement that "NOWHERE in the literature is there an example of proving nontriviality of any Brunnian n-link", technically this is false.  You might want to qualify your statement.  Are you talking about an infinite family?  Milnor invariants work, similarly finite-type invariants work, like Koschorke invariants.  I think perhaps you are not quite using English correctly, as the Whitehead links and Borromean rings are known to be non-trivial.

Comment: . . . and technically, any non-trivial knot is a non-trivial Brunnian 1-link.

Comment: Another tool in the arsenal is to go one more step and drill out the Hopf-linking circle for your link in the n=1 case.  If you can argue its exterior is hyperbolic, you could potentially argue your family is also hyperbolic, via covering spaces and filling.

Comment: Milnor's $\mu$ invariants are among the easiest ways to show nontriviality of a given Brunnian link but you can also pick your favorite link invariant like the Jones Polynomial and try calculating that. For mu invariants, Cochran's derived link calculus is pretty efficient in practice.

Comment: It's maybe worth noting that the fundamental argument you suggest does not work for the link in the picture. Each component is freely homotopic (not isotopic!) in the complement of the other (n-1) components to the unlink.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion about decision problems. The word problem is indeed undecidable in an *arbitrary* finitely presented group, but is easily decidable in a *free* group, which is your situation. You do this by writing your conjugacy class as a cyclically reduced word.

Answer (score 2):

In a comment to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/424215/1650) I give some of the details of a hyperbolic geometry proof that the link shown is non-trivial.  That proof works only when $n$ is large; in fact all links in the family (except for the first) are hyperbolic and thus non-trivial.  The first link in the family is actually a knot -- it is the connect sum of a pair of trefoils and so is non-trivial.