# Wrapping a suitcase with large rotational symmetry

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, knot-theory, knot-link

*This is a follow-up question to [Can I wrap a suitcase with hair ties](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424215/can-i-wrap-a-suitcase-with-hair-ties).*

Now we know that it is possible to wrap a suitcase with hair ties without tying them together,

> but can you do it with large rotational symmetry?

In other words, I am looking for a nontrivial link $L$ in a solid torus made by short circles that is trivial in the ambient euclidean space and such that $L$ is invariant with respect to a large cyclic group of rotations of the solid torus.

Comment: If you modify the question to ask for invariance under a cyclic group acting on  $S^3$ without fixed points, then I think it will be possible.

Comment: @IanAgol I am interested. (Altho it has no applications for  application to loom bracelet designs.)

Comment: @IanAgol - but this can be done by taking a disjoint union of many copies of the previous solution......  Suppose that U is the usual solid torus in S^3.  Let V_i be n copies of the solid torus, each embedded in U, each meeting the meridian disk of U once, and no V_i linking any V_j (thought of inside of S^3).  Then we can put the previous solution inside of each of the V_i and we are done.

Comment: @SamNead I did not formulate it precisely, but I wanted geometric symmetry. Your symmetry is only topological.

Comment: If you arrange the V_i symmetrically, and place the copies of the link inside the V_i symmetrically, then the result will have a geometric symmetry.  (This is similar to the construction of lens spaces.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit: my previous answer was incorrect**

No, this one you cannot do. If one had such an arrangement of circles in the solid torus inside $R^3$, and quotiented by a rotation, then by the [equivariant Dehn's lemma](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02566211) there would be a collection of essential disks in the complement of the split link that are invariant under the symmetry.

Since the link components get permuted, no disk can have a fixed point of the cyclic action. So they are disjoint from the axis of symmetry of the rotation.
Hence the components are unknotted in the solid torus, a contradiction